# add space between 1st and 2nd row in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table styled with bootstrap and want to add more padding between the header row and the rest of the rows (in other words between 1st and 2nd row). Solutions I found and tried:

```
tr.spaceUnder > td
{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

This works except that my cells are coloured so it doesn't actually add white space between the 2 rows which is what I need.

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 1em; 
}
```

This adds white space which is exactly what I need except it adds it between all the rows. One of the comments to this said that changing

```
border-spacing: 1em;
```

to

```
border-spacing: 0 1em;
```

is more specific and should add white space between the 1st and 2nd row only but it didn't change anything for me.

my table structure: http://pastebin.com/9QYVE5ZB (it's basically a calendar).

Comment: share your table structure.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9QYVE5ZB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply apply the `padding-bottom` for the header class. Look at the below CSS and my fiddle.

```
 #myTable th.header{padding-bottom:15px;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvm5xe23/1/)

Comment: I know I accepted this as an answer but I just realised that this solution doesn't work. It does the same thing, if the table row has borders or a specific background color then it would just make the cells higher. What I need is to make it add WHITE unbreakable space between the rows.

Comment: This doesn't change anything - I tried changing padding to margin on your jsfiddle and it didn't work.

Comment: check the above fiddle i have given in my comment

Comment: yes, can you please explain why that works? is it because you're adding it to the thead element rather than individual th-s?

Answer (score -1):

When I needed to do something similar, I used a `span` element inside the `td` and `th`.  So it will be my background color and then give the `td`, `th` padding bottom with no background.